# 'Results to be declared by the college': to be + past participal

Tags: tenses

I always get confused by the sentence structure 'to be + past participal'. What does that mean – present perfect or future?
Like in this sentence:

- *Results to be declared by the college*.

Results are declared? Results will be declared?

Also as in this sentence:

- *An announcement to be made*.

Is this correct or should it be

- *An announcement will be made*?

Comment: You need _is_ or _are_ with your 'to be+ past particip**le**'. "The results are to be declared" means that there is a formal arrangement to announce the results at a certain time. "An announcement _is_ to be made" means the same as "...will be made".

Comment: results are to be declared means it will be declared? I mean future context?

Comment: Actually I received an email from my college and they have this heading 'Status report as on 28/5/2019 of results to be declared by the college' and they have given so many results of the past dates also.

Comment: As the heading for a list, it implies 'results [which are] to be declared...'. If the list includes past results, I don't know why they don't just call it 'results declared by the college'.

Answer (score 1):

The *be+past participle* construction is a [passive infinitive](https://www.thoughtco.com/passive-infinitive-grammar-1691488).

The words '*results to be declared by the college*' contains an example of the passive infinitive, and can be converted to the active as *'the college to declare the results'*.

Note that neither of these two alternatives contains a finite verb, and so would not be considered complete sentences in traditional grammar.

Such constructions are often seen in headlines in order to save space. The *to + (passive) infinitive* replaces a future construction such as *will* or *is going to*.

So in this case, *'results to be declared'* means *'results will be declared*'. And both *'an announcement to be made'* and '*an announcement will be made*' are 'correct', but only the latter is a complete sentence.

There's an article about *headlinese* in Wikipedia, which contains the extract:
"...the future is expressed by an infinitive, with *to* followed by a verb, as in '*Governor to sign bill*'".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese

Comment: But they have already provided a list of results which are already declared and some yet to declare. Then why they use this construction for present perfect, past perfect and for future perfect all at the same time? Because list contains results of 2016 also.

Comment: @Rocky. Can the email you received be considered the 'declaration' of the results, in which case the email heading is confusing? Or is the email sending you the current 'status report' of the results, but the 'declaration' of those results, whatever form that might take, has not happened yet?

Comment: I think 'to be declared' means results yet to come. But they have results of 2016 also in that list. In that case it should be like this ' results have been declared' 'to be declared' as far as I know means 'yet to come'. Am I right?

Comment: @Rocky. '_To be declared_ can only mean '_that will be declared_'. If the email you got also includes past results then strictly speaking the heading would have to be: _Status report as on 28/5/2019 of results (already) declared and to be declared by the college'_. Or _Status report as on 28/5/2019 of the results that have already been declared and will be declared by the college'_. But then we are venturing far away from the typical _headlinese_ of email headings.

Comment: Okay I got your point.