# Can we use a to-infinitive directly after the subject?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, verbs, infinitives

- *Hong Kong to ban flights from India, Bangladesh.*

Is the above sentence grammatically correct?
OR
does it require a verb:

- *Hong Kong is to ban flights from India, Bangladesh.*

So, basically ... which sentence is grammatically correct?

Comment: The first sentence is in 'newspaper headline' style, often called [headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline#Headlinese), in which, among other conventions, forms of the verb "to be" and articles (a, an, the) are usually omitted.

Comment: @Michael Harvey So, according to grammar sentence having verb is correct

Comment: Yes, for normal text, not headlines, a verb is required.

Comment: @Michael Harvey So in this case, Hong Kong is to ban...... Is correct, am I right?

Comment: @Michael Harvey OR   " is going to ban "     is correct?

Comment: As Michael explained, your versions would be correct _in a normal sentence_ - but the version you quoted is perfectly acceptable as a newspaper headline.

Comment: @Kate Bunting But which 'is' or 'is going to' or both

Comment: 'Is to', 'is going to', plans to. 'intends to'... However you choose to interpret the headline!

Comment: You can think of the way headlines, and some other items such as entries in service logs are written, as being a little like the way people used to write telegrams which were charged by the word. Things like "Home tomorrow meet 4:45" which would have meant "I will be home tomorrow, darling. Please meet me at the local station, I will be on the 4:45 train." The longer version would have cost a fortune to send.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Results to be declared by the college': to be + past participal](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/499923/results-to-be-declared-by-the-college-to-be-past-participal)

Answer (score 1):

> *Hong Kong to ban flights from India, Bangladesh.*

It's a compressed (possibly by the headline writer) newspaper headline. It is to be understood as "Hong Kong is/intends to ban flights from India and Bangladesh".

Marginally ungrammatical. Yet we understood it instantly. What this teaches us is that ungrammaticality is gradient, and humans are amazingly tolerant of slight departures from full grammaticality.

Comment: I corrected the original and adjusted the quote. // I've data-banked your second paragraph, and will, with permission, quote it when amazingly intolerant humans misuse 'incorrect'.